# Hydro and Indigo in parallel?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, multi-machine, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
is it possible to use for example a listener build of hydro and on a other machine a talker build with indigo? On which machine has the roscore running?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183042/hydro-and-indigo-in-parallel?/) by [Yeti2](https://answers.ros.org/users/19455/yeti2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will generally work, unless message definitions between rosdistros have changed (then, you´ll get errors about md5sum missmatches when trying to establish topic connections). As most messages types are stable by now and do not get changed between distros, it is unlikely you´ll run into problems. See also this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/107961/multiple-machine-communication-from-hydro-to-groovy/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-05**:
The Diagnostic message changed between Hydro and Indigo, so exchanging diagnostic information between machines running different distros will not work.

**Comment by [Yeti2](https://answers.ros.org/users/19455/yeti2/) on 2014-07-07**:
Thanks for the answers. Now the listener and talker are running with differen versions. The probelm was a network configuration problem.